# Can I have a second menu bar on my secondary display?

Tags: software-recommendation, menu-bar, display

Is there software that will allow you to add a second menu bar to a secondary display? I am using [Second Bar,](http://blog.boastr.net/?page_id=79) but I was wondering if there was other software out there that would do this. Note that I don't want to *move* the menu bar. I know I can move the menu bar in System Preferences. This is not what I want. I want a *second* menu bar.

Comment: One app that I've found useful for working with multiple monitors is [DejaMenu](http://homepage.mac.com/khsu/DejaMenu/DejaMenu.html). It gives you the menu bar as a context menu when you press a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I never tried Second Bar: why do you want an alternative solution?

Comment: @Matteo Second Bar is a bit buggy, and I was wondering if anyone else had used something else.

Comment: @NathanGreenstein BTW, DejaMenu is pretty cool!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, no there is not another app that currently provides the same functionality as Second Bar.

[MenuEverywhere](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/34931/menueverywhere) or [DejaMenu](http://homepage.mac.com/khsu/DejaMenu/DejaMenu.html) provide other workarounds to make menu bar commands selectable elsewhere, but I am not aware of any other program that puts a menu bar on multiple monitors.

Answer (score 0):

[Multimon](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/multimon/id522324709?ls=1&mt=12)

"adds a menubar to your second (or third, or so on) display and gives you hotkeys to quickly move windows from one monitor to another. You also get a menubar icon to click and move windows. When it does move windows, it automatically scales and resizes them for you to match the target monitor's resolution." - [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5917662/multimon-adds-multiple-menubars-automatic-window-resizing-to-your-multi+monitor-mac)

Note: not free ($10)